# how to select data those out of both table have

Tags: mysql

this question is a bit of a mouthful.

express this question by example

there are two table here:

```
table1
id1    col1
 1       a
 2       b
 3       c
---------------------
table2
id2    col2
 1       b
 2       c
 3       d
```

if i do this: `select * from table1 t inner join table2 tt on t.col1=tt.col2`
l will get the result like this:

```
id1   col1   id2    col2
  2      b     1       b
  3      c     2       c
```

than question coming

l want to get result like this

```
 id1   col1   id2    col2
   1      a  null    null
null   null     3       d
```

Comment: You want a full outer join: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You would normally use a Full outer join but in mysql you can try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t
LEFT JOIN table2 tt ON t.col1=tt.col2
UNION
SELECT * FROM table2 tt
LEFT JOIN table1 t ON t.col1=tt.col2
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but full outer join doesn't work in mysql, but l got the result l wanted by using the union operator

Comment: @afraid.jpg sorry about that I missed the MySQL tag. I have corrected my answer.